# Python - Reset button calculator and other issues

Tags: python, calculator

Python - Reset button calculator and other issues

This is a python calculator. I developed a part here. but, In this calculator, when the user enters two wrong numbers or one wrong operator, the reset function is given by $ + enter. How to add reset capability to code?

How to fix it?

## Program make a simple calculator

```
# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y
# This function uses to power 
def power(x, y):
    return x**y
    
# This function uses for the remainder
def remainder (x, y):
    return x % y


print("Please select the operation.")
print("1:Add")
print("2:Subtract")
print("3:Multiply")
print("4:Divide")
print("5:Power")
print("6:remainder")
print("7.Terminate")
print("8.Reset")

while True:
    # take input from the user
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4/5/6): ")

    # check if choice is one of the four options
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4','5' ,'6'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

        if choice == '1':
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '2':
            print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '3':
            print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '4':
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
        
        elif choice == '5':
            print(num1, "**", num2, "=", power(num1, num2))
        elif choice == '6':
            print(num1, "%", num2, "=", remainder(num1, num2))
        elif choice == '7':
            print(num1 , "#", num2, "=", terminate(num1,num2))    
        
        next_calculation = input("Let's do  next     calculation? (yes/no): ")
    if next_calculation == "no":
        print("Thank you")
        
        #this funtion uses to optimize the code [ select_op(choice) funtion also used here ]
def find(choice):        
    if reset_operand == "yes":
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
        select_op(choice)
    elif reset_operand == "no":
        select_op(choice)
        # take input from the user
    
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4/5/6): ")
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'):
        reset_operation = input("Do you need to change the operation? (yes/no): ")
        if reset_operation == "yes":
            choice = input("Enter again choice(1/2/3/4/5/6): ")
            num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
            reset_operand = input("Do you need to change the reset_operand? (yes/no): ")
            
        if reset_operation == "no":
            if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'):
                num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
                num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
                reset_operand = input("Do you need to change the reset_operand? (yes/no): ")
                find(choice)
          
    
    else:
        print("Unrecongnized operation !")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the while(true) will continue to run even if 7 or 8 is selected because there is no if statement to break out of the while loop.

Comment: @AndrewRyan yes how to add?

Comment: @Malshan you could do an `else:` in the while(true) before the next_caluclation or you could do an `elif choice in ('7' , '8'):`

Comment: @AndrewRyan Ok. But the code is still not working

Comment: @Malshan can you update your question and tell us more specifically what the problems you are having?

Comment: @Malshan you also don't use `find()` at all so you aren't getting any functionality from that function